# change order of square in sfDatePicker

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, syncfusion

I have a sfdatepicker in my windows app project
but when i use it the SfDateSelector appears in american format, and i want to change it to european (day/month/year)

```
<Syncfusion:SfDatePicker  x:Name="SearchDate1" Grid.Column="0"  AccentBrush="{StaticResource BrandBrush}" />
```

for example on image bellow i want to see 09 11 2015

[image]

how can i achieve that?

Comment: indeed the out of box picker also shows november 9 2015, altho i have computer configured to Portugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `SelectorFormatString="d/m/y"` on your DatePicker. See https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5307/how-can-i-set-different-patterns-for-the-date-in-the-sfdatepicker